# What is the updated lifecycle hook in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, hook, lifecycle

What can I do with this lifecycle hook?

In Vue, I want to delete values from an array and save new ones, but it wont show, if I don't refresh the page. Can I refresh it without reloading the page with this life cycle hook?

Comment: The updated lifecicle hook is executed after each re-render on the screen, the re-render occurs when a value that is displayed changes and the screen needs to be updated. I'm not sure that is a good point to manage the array you mentioned. You can see more about the lifecicle hooks here - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram

Comment: You indeed have all the details for the lifecycle with Vue3 in the link given in the comment above. For Vue2, the name is different but you should not be using Vue2 anymore anyway so if it's the case, please migrate because the EOL is for end of 2023.